# Angular 5 + Firebase Profile

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase for authentication on my Angular 5 application and I also have a form used to update 'photoURL' and 'displayName' from Firebase account.

The problem is that, when I try to update these field, I have this error in my console, but the fieldsn are updating on firebase.
The weid part is that this happens only on my live site, not on localhost. On localhost everything works fine.

This is my code, using only methods from Firebase and calling this function from another component, passing an object as parameter, containing those 2 properties.

```js
updateProfile(user: User) {
    return this._firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser
      .updateProfile(user)
      .then(res => {
        this.alertService.info(
          'Your profile has been successfully updated!',
          false
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.alertService.error(error.message);
      });
  }
```

[image: click here to see the error message]

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"